# Populate combobox in UWP using Entity Framework

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

Hello I'm currently new to UWP and trying to populate combo box by using Entity Framework.

But My App doesn't display anything when code runs.

Please can anyone solve this issue? As far as I remember this was the way it was done for WPF.

[image]

Here is my Xaml Code

[image]

Comment: May you give us the code and not a picture of it? This way we could help you better working with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
        ddlemp_title.ItemsSource = db.Titles.ToList();
        ddlemp_title.DisplayMemberPath = "Title_Name";
        ddlemp_title.SelectedValuePath = "TitleId";
        ddlemp_title.SelectedValue = -1;
```